# responsive / bootstrap.css menu titles

Tags: html, css

Not sure if anyone can help me. But here's the issue. I'm making a mobile website for personal use and having a heck of a time with a free template I downloaded...

I'm wondering how I can put a title on a responsive menu of a website. When the site is visited on a desktop, a normal menu shows fine. However, when visiting on a mobile device or tablet, the site should automatically collapse the menu (which it does) and then show a single menu title that users can interact with.

Using google chrome I can inspect the element and find either a nav.php or bootstrap-responsive.css file that I can edit in order to add the menu title.

Can anyone provide any insight? I'm not sure what I need to post... The site is http://bit.ly/15TpCjW

Thanks! Let me know if I need to provide any other information!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the class of brand below each icon set in your nav.php files (depending on the menu that you want to edit) will accomplish this.